# Add to my solution folder with exe file that i want to run

Tags: c#

I added to my application folder with exe file that i want to run from my application but i think I did not run the exe file properly.
For example my folder name is folder and the exe file is run.exe so i try `@"\folder\run.exe"` but The system cannot find the file specified.
what is the correct way to do it ?

```
public void run(string filePath, int deviceNumber)
{
    ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"\folder\run.exe");
    processStartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {2}{1}{2}", (deviceNumber).ToString(), filePath, "\"");
    processStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    processStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    processStartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;

    using (Process process = Process.Start(processStartInfo))
    {
        process.WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

ISSUE SOLVED:

```
the way to do it is ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + myEXEpath);
```

Comment: Are you doing this through VS or programmatically?

Comment: How your are trying to run that exe??

Answer (score 0):

If you run it using Process Class remove the leading backslash

```
@"folder\run.exe"
```

The directory "folder" must be in the same directory with your executable.

Comment: still The system cannot find the file specified

Answer (score 0):

When you start your app from VS you could start processes programatically like this:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\somepath\run.exe");
```

You can set the process path relative to your app path. 
Like that:

```
Process.Start(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory+"run.exe");
```

You can run this from program.cs and run it at same time of you application start or start it on an other event like form load, or a button click.

Comment: still The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Debug your code, and add the path to a variable, or copy it into the watch section. Watch the value at runtime, what is it exactly. And watch the path wich you see in the debug mode, and check it whether is it correct.

Comment: IMHO it's better to use `System.IO.Path.Combine` rather than concatenating strings for filepaths. It might save you someday :-)